# manipulate the JSON object converted from a java Map

Tags: java, javascript, json

Inside my action I've computed a json object from a map and I get:

```
{"angleEqual(angle(a,d,c),angle(a,e,b)).":{"allLinesId":"['DA','CD','AE','BE']","numberOfLinesWithinAGroup":2}}
```

When it comes to the front end it looked fine under the chrome debugging console, however, (driving me mad!!) how do I get the content of the value under the attribute of allLinesId and display, I thought it should be straightforward to do:

```
var object= data.angleEqual(angle(a,d,c),angle(a,e,b)).;
object.allLinesId;
object.display;
```

Not worked out as a solution, thanks a lot if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the bracket notation.

```js
var object = data['angleEqual(angle(a,d,c),angle(a,e,b)).'];
object.allLinesId;
object.display;
```